# What is the GTS(Guarantee Time Slot) in Super Frame Structure?

Tags: zigbee

http://alkautsarpens.files.wordpress.com/2008/01/f66.jpg

I wanna know the main job of GTS in this frame in PAN-Personal Area Network ?
Are they (the GTSs) have a fixed number per frame ?
& What kind of devices in PAN will use these GTS and for what reasons or which cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PAN Coordinator or any Coordinator in PAN can assign GTS to devices in his network , the GTSs takes one or more Time-Slots .
These GTSs used to let the devices send their data any time they want instead of using CSMA/CA mechanism .